# How can I install an older version of npm even though I already have a newer version, in order to get react native working

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Trying to use react native but apparently the newest version of npm doesn't work with it. How can I install an older version. Thorough instructions  would be very helpful. Thanks

Also, I am VERY new to this entire programming thing. I know some basic JavaScript an decent Python but that's about it, is I too early for me to attempt to learn react native

Comment: What error u get while using newest version of npm ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

First uninstall existing npm using `npm uninstall npm -g` command .

Then remove nodejs.

Install nodejs again.

Now, install npm using `npm install -g npm@4.6.1`